# Problem installing a w2k DC on Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v

We have a cluster with four node windows 2008 r2 and hyper-v installed. 
We would like to install 2 VM with role domain controller w2k (the domain is different from the domain of the hyper-v cluster).
Do you know if there are any restriction on doing it? Some collegues say that we risk data corruption if we do live migrations. Others speak about the fact that Microsoft don't support w2k any more. And others have doubts because the global catalog server installed on these DC could have loss of performance.

Any idea?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: I dont understand your question. Are you just looking to install some W2K VMs and add them as additional DCs to your domain? If so, why? Are you looking to setup a parallel domain to your 2008 environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to actually use them as production servers I'd probably recommend against it.
They work fine from what I've seen, as long as you follow the directions, but they don't perform really well. Is there some specific reason you want to run a Windows 2000 domain server instead of just making it a member server in your existing domain and hosting whatever legacy apps are required on it?

Edit: Actually, checking the Hyper-V gues OS list it looks like they removed Server 2000 from the list.

[Hyper-V Guest List](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-supported-guest-os.aspx)